# Mediawiki: How to prevent images in wikitext from beeing rendered in html?

Tags: html, image, mediawiki, wikitext

To offer a mobile version of an existing mediawiki installation I was looking for a practicable way to remove all images from output. The most preferred solution would be one where the generated html would no longer contain the image-tags.
As I was not able to figure out a clean solution I moved the images to a different server and disabled $wgForeignFileRepos and $wgAllowExternalImages in this version.
Unfortunately - while the images are not shown - there appears a placeholder box containing the image's name and a (now not functioning) link to it.

Do you know about a way to get rid of the images without using css/js or a way to bring my approach to completion?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [javascript mobile browswer detection](http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/) and then on detection it runs the following javascript code.

```
var imagesremove = document.getElementsByTag('img')
imagesremove.parentNode.removeChild(imagesremove);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better solutions, but you can override the [ImageBeforeProduceHTML hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ImageBeforeProduceHTML) to make images generate empty output:

```
$wgHooks['ImageBeforeProduceHTML'][] = function( &$skin, &$title, &$file, &$frameParams, &$handlerParams, &$time, &$res ) {
    $res = '';
    return false;
}
```

...or something more fancy, such as returning a link to the image instead of an actual `<img>` tag.

Depending on your wiki's caching settings, you might have to purge the page cache afterwards, e.g. by setting [$wgCacheEpoch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCacheEpoch).